# Pixels covered inside an irregular design

Tags: javascript

I paint freehand strokes on my canvas using javascript, it's always a bounded shaped design.
Is it able to find the number of pixels covered inside that bounded strokes.

I need help in how to calculate the pixels inside an irregular bounded shaped design.

I am new to this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just told us what it is _able_ to do, but where exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem exists how can we calculate the pixels inside an irregular bounded shaped design. i took an example from here  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC8cB/3/) draw a pattern

Comment: ok, now edit your answer and add what you just told me.